# Symfony 4 Serializer: deserializing request and merging it with entity including relation that is not completely passed by client

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, symfony4

Let's say I have a entity called User:

```
class User implements UserInterface
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
     private $username;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;
```

The address field is a OneToOne relation to the address entity:

```
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

And I have a Controller for updating the user and his address:

```
...
 public function putUserSelf(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()));

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $user = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), User::class, "json", ['deep_object_to_populate' => $user]);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
```

In theory I should now be possible to pass a json like this:

```
{
    "username": "foo",
    "address": {"name": "bar"}
}
```

to update my entity. But the problem is, that I get a sql error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO address (street, name) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, "bar"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'street' cannot be null
```

It seems like the entity merge did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-in-an-existing-object),

> When the `AbstractObjectNormalizer::DEEP_OBJECT_TO_POPULATE` option is set to **true**, existing children of the root `OBJECT_TO_POPULATE` are updated from the normalized data, instead of the denormalizer re-creating them. [...]
>   (emphasis mine)

so you have to set an *extra* option, so your line should be:

```
    $user = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), User::class, "json", [
        'object_to_populate' => $user, // this still needs to be set, without the "deep_"
        'deep_object_to_populate' => true,
    ]);
```

there is some additional comment in the source code of the specific component:

> ```
> /**
>  * Flag to tell the denormalizer to also populate existing objects on
>  * attributes of the main object.
>  *
>  * Setting this to true is only useful if you also specify the root object
>  * in OBJECT_TO_POPULATE.
>  */
> public const DEEP_OBJECT_TO_POPULATE = 'deep_object_to_populate';
> ```
>
> source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d8a026bcadb46c9955beb25fc68080c54f2cbe1a/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php#L82