# Symfony Serializer: Deserialize with relation

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I test the serializer component and try to do the following.

I have an Article entity:

```php
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Comment::class, mappedBy="article", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $comments;

//getter/setter...
```

and a Comment entity :

```php
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Article::class, inversedBy="comments", cascade={ "persist" })
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $article;

//getter/setter...
```

When a send a json to the controller:

```json
{
    "title": "My comment",
    "content": "This is a comment",
    "article": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

- Article with id `1` exists

I would like the relationship with Article to be deserialized:

```php
 #[Route('', name: "comment_create", methods: ['POST'])]
    public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse 
    {
        $comment = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), Comment::class, 'json');
//        $this->entityManager->persist($comment);
//        $this->entityManager->flush();
        return $this->json($comment, Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

but the article is not linked.

```json
{"id":null,"title":"My comment","content":"This is a comment","article":{"id":null,"title":null,"content":null,"comments":[]}}
```

Where is my mistake ? Can the symfony serializer do this ?

Comment: wich serializer are you using jms or symfony serializer ?

Comment: The symfony serializer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 4 Serializer: deserializing request and merging it with entity including relation that is not completely passed by client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157359/symfony-4-serializer-deserializing-request-and-merging-it-with-entity-including)

Comment: Unfortunately not despite my tests

Comment: Please update your question with what you tried and the changes you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following for deserialization:

```php
$comment = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), 'App\Entity\Comment', 'json');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution. Please note that "code only" Answers are accepted, though are generally discouraged. Consider [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71719245/5411817) your post to add an explanation as to how/why your code solves the OP's issue. Sometimes a link to documentation can also help. Quality answers help visitors learn something that they can use to apply to their own coding issues, thus they tend to receive more upvotes over time. Explanations help more people overall, & tend to be the most appreciated. Looking forward to more contributions. Happy coding.